# Can't use .Union all with Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a problem, can you help me.

```
var query = (from MONHOC in db.tbl_MONHOCs
                where
                    (MONHOC.IS_DELETE != 1 ||
                     MONHOC.IS_DELETE == null) &&
                    MONHOC.ISBATBUOC == 1
                select new
                {
                    ID = ("MH_CHA_" + Convert.ToString(MONHOC.ID_MONHOC)),
                    ID_NAME = MONHOC.ID_MONHOC,
                    MA_MONHOC = MONHOC.MA_MONHOC,
                    NAME = MONHOC.TEN_MONHOC,
                    ID_PARENT = 0
                }).Concat
                (from MONHOC in db.tbl_MONHOCs
                    where
                        (MONHOC.IS_DELETE != 1 ||
                         MONHOC.IS_DELETE == null) &&
                        MONHOC.ISBATBUOC == 0
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = ("MH_CON_" + Convert.ToString(MONHOC.ID_MONHOC)),
                        ID_NAME = MONHOC.ID_MONHOC,
                        MA_MONHOC = MONHOC.MA_MONHOC,
                        NAME = MONHOC.TEN_MONHOC,
                        ID_PARENT = (int?) MONHOC.ID_MONHOC_CHA
                    }
                );
```

Error

> Error Compiling Expression: Error Compiling Expression:
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Concat(System.Linq.ParallelQuery,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid
>   arguments Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message "clearly" :) tells you that the types of the properties in the anonymous types don't match.

In the first part you have:

```
ID_PARENT = 0
```

In the second part:

```
ID_PARENT = (int?) MONHOC.ID_MONHOC_CHA
```

These properties should both either be `int?` or `int`.